# How to ceiling or floor a variable?

Tags: php, math

I have tried to use some algorithms made for other languages for ceiling variables and flooring them, I looked up in the PHP Manual for answers but couldn't manage to find any answers as to finding the floor / ceiling.

I have tried setting my precision to `0` in the PHP.INI and that didn't change anything.

I have also tried `3 / 2` and I want that to give me `1 (floor) as answer or 2 (ceil)`

Comment: `3 / 2` and `1 / 2` are not equals.. What is your idea about this?? Do you mean `3 / 2 = 1` and  `1 / 2 = 1`???

Comment: I think that he means it give him 1 `(floored)` or 2 `(ceiling)` @FrayneKonok

Comment: Your thinking does not match with OP.

Comment: @FrayneKonok I think you should cut Jek some slack, the OP is not clear either.

Comment: @FrayneKonok - Jek is right - He knows what I'm thinking

Comment: That's why i am asking the `OP` for some clearance..

Comment: @FrayneKonok Sorry last bit wasn't me, the bit about me calling you an ass

Comment: Here we go, take a look at the answer. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37427340/how-to-ceiling-or-floor-a-variable/37427473#37427473](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37427340/how-to-ceiling-or-floor-a-variable/37427473#37427473)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ceiling or floor a variable it is as simple as using the PHP builtin math functions:

```
$ceiling = ceil(1.5);   // Ceiling of 3/2 is 2

$floor   = floor(1.5);  // Floor of 3/2 is 1
```

`ceil` takes a float and returns a float rounded up to the nearest integer.  `floor` takes a float and returns a float rounded down to the nearest integer.  See:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php

Answer (score 0):

This is it what you are looking for. Online Example: https://3v4l.org/p98hs

```
$var = (3 / 2);

echo floor($var); // 1
echo ceil($var);  // 2
```